# How can i use this code for filtering all column of grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I  use this code in my grid view, but it just filter one 
 column of  my grid view.
I want  to add other column to  this code, I'm using it for loop but the code doesn't work right.

How can i change this code to achieve filtering in other column not one column ?

There is one column filtering code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //
            // Client Side Search (Autocomplete)
            // Get the search Key from the TextBox
            // Iterate through the 1st Column.
            // td:nth-child(1) - Filters only the 1st Column
            // If there is a match show the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]
            // Else hide the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]
          { $('#filter').keyup(function (event) {
                var searchKey = $(this).val();

                $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr td:nth-child(4)").each(function () {
                    var cellText = $(this).text();
                    if (cellText.indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
                        $(this).parent().show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).parent().hide();}

                });

            });

        });
```

And there is the code for all columns:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //
            // Client Side Search (Autocomplete)
            // Get the search Key from the TextBox
            // Iterate through the 1st Column.
            // td:nth-child(1) - Filters only the 1st Column
            // If there is a match show the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]
            // Else hide the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]
          { $('#filter').keyup(function (event) {
                var searchKey = $(this).val();
              for(i=0;i<5;++i)
               {    $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr td:nth-child(i)").each(function () {
                    var cellText = $(this).text();
                    if (cellText.indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
                        $(this).parent().show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).parent().hide();}

                });

            });   }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
for(i=0; i<5; ++i) {
     $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr td:nth-child(i)").each(function () {
```

With this:

```
for(i=1; i<6; ++i) {
     $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr td:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function () {
```

`i` is actually a javascript variable here, but its interpreted as a string in your code. Also, [`:nth-child() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) starts with 1, so we need to modify the for loop too.

Comment: it dos not  work right too i test your code it just  filter my last column of grid any body know other thing i think i have to use such this thing  $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 thead tr:nth-child(i)").each(function () { i don't know is it true ? i want filter all of column of grid